# Video playback in a list using exoplayer

Tags: android, exoplayer

I have a list of elements in a `RecyclerView`, some of which include a `SimpleExoPlayerView`. When the `RecyclerView` first shows an element with a `SimpleExoPlayerView`, the video loads just fine. However, when I scroll away (such that the element isn't shown on the screen) and then scroll back. The video doesn't play (or load) at all. Why is this happening and how can I change it so that when I do scroll back to the `SimpleExoPlayerView` containing element I can hit play and resume from the position it was paused in (let's assume the video didn't go all the way to completion).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best answer, however, it worked for me. Originally I called `prepare()` on the `SimpleExoPlayer` in `onBindViewHolder()`. I noticed that the code from that method isn't called again when the `ViewHolder` reappears on the screen. I simply called the `prepare()` method again during `onViewAttachedToWindow()`.